# vuejs: removed child component can still get event message from parent

Tags: vue.js

I came across this issue in my project, and I reproduce it in the following demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/jeeh5ncp/

Briefly speaking,

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    newitem: '',
    allData: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.allData.push(this.newitem);
    },
    sendMessage() {
      Bus.$emit('send-message');
    },
    showAll() {
      console.log(this.allData.length);
    },
  },
})
```

I use `addItem` method add item to the allData property,which is a list. And `sendMessage` to emit event out, which will be listened by child  component. The `showAll` is  simply show the current length of the allData list.

for the child component, it goes as following :

```
Vue.component('service', {
  template: '<div>' +
    '<span>{{serviceName}}</span>' +
    '<button @click="remove">X</button>' +
    '</div>',
  props: ['serviceName', 'index'],
  methods: {
    remove() {
      this.$emit('remove');
    },
  },
  created() {
    Bus.$on('send-message', () => {
      console.log(this.index);
    })
  },
})
```

Each child component can be removed by click the `x` button. And in the `created` hook, set up the event listen for `send-message`.

the HTML part is as following:

```
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="newitem">
  <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
  <button @click="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
  <button @click="showAll">Show</button>
  <service v-for="(each, index) in allData" :service-name="each" @remove="allData.splice(index,1)"  :index="index"></service>
</div>
```

The confusing point is, for example I add 3 child component. And click the `send Message` button, I can get `0 1 2`, which is expected. But if I remove one child element, and click the `send Message` button,  still get `0 1 2`.  But the length  is `2`. So what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are setting an event listener on the Bus, you need to manually remove the listener when the component is destroyed:

```
methods: {
  remove() {
    this.$emit('remove');
  },
  logIndex() {
    console.log(this.index)
  }
},
created() {
  Bus.$on('send-message', this.logIndex)
},
destroyed() {
  Bus.$off('send-message', this.logIndex)
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jeeh5ncp/3/)